# Facing issue with Execute Sql Task

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012

I am having issue with Execute script task.
Currently the task is executing stored procedure and result is assigned to variable.
Now I want to execute both the stored procedure and sql select statement in single execute task
I tried to acheive it by using dynamic sql statements as shown below.

SQl Script

```
 DECLARE @Query                  NVARCHAR(250)
DECLARE @ParmDefinition         NVARCHAR(250)
DECLARE @Id           int
DECLARE @Usr_Id         VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @TCId       INT
DECLARE @IsSuccess         bit

Set @Query = 'Exec InsertSp @Id,@Usr_Id,@TCId OUTPUT'
 
SET @ParmDefinition = '@Id INT,@Usr_Id VARCHAR(50),@TCId INT OUTPUT'
 
EXEC sp_executesql @Query,   
     @ParmDefinition,
     @Id=2,
     @Usr_Id='domain\fn.lastname',
     @TCId=@TCId OUTPUT

Set @Query = 'SELECT  TOP (1) @IsSuccessOut = IsSuccess
FROM dbo.TableA AS a
INNER JOIN dbo.TableB AS b
ON a.Id = b.Id
WHERE (b.Name = ''LoadDaily'')
ORDER BY StartTime DESC'
 
SET @ParmDefinition = '@IsSuccessOut INT OUTPUT'

EXEC sp_executesql @Query,@ParmDefinition,@IsSuccessOut=@IsSuccess output

SELECT @TCId AS 'TCId',@IsSuccess as 'IsSuccess'
```

I created variable and assigned the above query to it.

In Execute SQl task,I have assigned the variable

[image]

i set result of the variable to two variables
[image]
When I am trying to run package, not able to get values of output to result variables. Please let me know how can i get out put of above sql.

Comment: When you write "not able to get values of output to result variables", what do you mean by that? Does the task error out? When the task completes, your user Variables do not contain the expected value, something else?

Comment: Task is success but user variables does not have output values of the sql query which should be executed  as part of task. Please let me know if there is any issue with sql query or my approach

Comment: If you replace the contents of the Execute SQL Task with a simplified `SELECT 0 AS 'TCId', CAST(1 AS bit) as 'IsSuccess'`  Do you see the values assigned? And either way, *how* are you determining whether the value was assigned?

Comment: Now I see I am getting error "[Execute SQL Task] Error: An error occurred while assigning a value to variable "TCId": "Exception from HRESULT: 0xC0015005".I added variables  to watch window and put break point to see if the value changes

Answer (score 0):

A simple version of your package works, so let's break it down.

[image]

Your Execute SQL Task has 3 variables at play. Whatever you crossed out in the first screenshot, which I will call `User::SQLSource` and is of type String. I have this defined as `SELECT 0 AS TCId, CAST(1 AS bit) as IsSuccess;`

I have two variables for the result set. `User::IsSuccess` which is a Boolean type and `User::TCId` which is type Int32.

### SCR Echo Back

I favor a script task like this to [echo the value of variables](https://billfellows.blogspot.com/2016/04/biml-script-task-test-for-echo.html) into the information event log

```
using System.Data;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ST_EchoBack
{
    [Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.SSISScriptTaskEntryPointAttribute]
    public partial class ScriptMain : Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTARTScriptObjectModelBase
    {
        public void Main()
        {
            bool fireAgain = false;
            string message = "{0}::{1} : {2}";
            foreach (var item in Dts.Variables)
            {
                Dts.Events.FireInformation(0, "SCR Echo Back", string.Format(message, item.Namespace, item.Name, item.Value), string.Empty, 0, ref fireAgain);
            }

            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
        }

        enum ScriptResults
        {
            Success = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Success,
            Failure = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Failure
        };
    }
}
```

### Where did it go wrong?

You should be able to recreate what I have shown here and get the same results. Once that's done, start adding your more complex pieces back in.

Given your error of

> Execute SQL Task: An error occurred while assigning a value to variable "TCId"

I could recreate that same error by having a query in my Execute SQL Task that generates a result set.

Multi-statements are fine as long as no recordsets are generated

```
DECLARE @foo int;
SELECT @foo = 1 FROM sys.tables AS T; 

SELECT 0 AS TCId, CAST(1 AS bit) AS IsSuccess;
```

Queries that generate results, will

```
DECLARE @foo int;
SELECT @foo = 1 FROM sys.tables AS T; 

-- This will mess things up.
SELECT 1, 1 FROM sys.tables;

SELECT 0 AS TCId, CAST(1 AS bit) AS IsSuccess;
```

I would take your existing query and run it in SSMS. One of your sp_executesql is generating a result set. There could also be a trigger associated to `InsertSp` that is generating a result set and that's fouling up the metadata.

The other thing I'd point out is you don't need to alias your columns with a single quote in your final statement there. SQL server uses square brackets, preferred, or double quotes if you must if you are dealing with a poorly named column.